# .htaccess + PHP to create dynamic Facebook-type navigation with some fixed links?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a fluid and dynamic interface, and I do love the way Facebook loads pages so that bits of the page are left intact (most importantly the chat section, top nav bar and footer), while the content you navigate to gets loaded asynchronously.

So.. What needs to be done in order to achieve such a system? What I'm thinking, is to have all link requests rerouted through `.htaccess` to some main "hub" PHP file that includes whatever content is requested by including the corresponding PHP file that handles that request. So if we were to request `/photos` in our nav bar, our request would go the .htaccess file, which would reroute the request to some `mainhub.php` file which in turn would include our `photos.php` file.

But I'm bumping into a few hiccups. If i reroute all traffic to `mainhub.php` with let's say this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mainhub.php [QSA]` then everything (images, css, js files etc) will also pass through the `mainhub.php` file. That's no good..

Also, just as Facebook has some pages that are not loaded asynchronously, but are properly navigated to (like the settings page), I'd also like to have that feature. So also there as to be a requirement for some pages not go through the `mainhub.php` file.

Another thing I'm not sure how to accomplish, is having the "sticky" content loaded when accessing a specific link. For example `/home` could be the home page and I could have the sticky bits hardcoded into the `home.php` file, and when the user navigates the website - request other pages and not include the bits that are static. Seems logical. But what happens if a user jumps into another page (not the `/home` page where I have the sticky parts coded), what do I do then?..

Maybe I'm thinking the wrong way with this, so I'm hoping some `.htaccess` + PHP guru could help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rerouting can be done with htaccess. **All files, directories and symlinks** will still be accessible, everything else is redirected to (in this case) `index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

**What you probably want** is to do some asynchronous loading with ajax. This is completly **independent** of any .htaccess rerouting.
For the ajax part: You could set a special css class to all links that should use ajax loading. Then use jQuery selector looking for this special class. You can set an on link click event that loads via ajax aswell. You'll probably want to use on of the bigger javascript frameworks like jQuery for this.
By checking the headers - you're able to distinguish between a non ajax call and an ajax call.